# Multi-Module Gradle project - Migrate from Spring-Boot 1.5 to 2.1

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, migration, multi-module

I would like to migrate a multimodule spring-boot 1.5 project to spring-boot 2.1. It is a gradle project (4.9), but somehow I dont get it solved.

With spring-boot 1.5.9 the application compiles fine and modules which are depending on other modules can also resolve the classes.

With upgrading to spring-boot 2.0 or 2.1 I am not able to get the one module resolving the classes of the other module.

In my project, the project api depends on library. Again, this build.gradle works fine for me with Spring Boot 1.5.9. I am happy with any help.

```
buildscript {
    ext { springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE' }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "o.s.b:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    group = 'n.h.f.calculator'
    version = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile       'o.c.groovy:groovy'
        testCompile   'o.s.b:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }
}

project(':' + rootProject.name + '-library') {
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    }
}

project(':' + rootProject.name + '-api') {
    dependencies {
        compile project (':' + rootProject.name + '-library')
        compile         'o.s.b:spring-boot-starter-web'
    }
}
```

I become then a compiler issue from module `*-api`, which say that classes of module `*-lib` cannot be resolved.

Example

```
C:\Development\Projects\Immosoft\financial-calculator\api\src\main\groovy\net\hemisoft\financial\calculator\api\BasicApi.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class net.hemisoft.financial.calculator.library.utils.BasicCalculator
@ line 7, column 1.
import net.hemisoft.financial.calculator.library.utils.BasicCalculator
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting at build or runtime?

Comment: I have Compiler issue of the Module, which cant find classes of the other modules which it is using. With spring-boot 1.5 is no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The magic words are `jar { enabled = true }` and `bootJar { enabled = false }`. I put it into the project which contains the library (backend classes) for the application.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "o.s.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

...

project(':' + rootProject.name + '-library') {
    dependencies {
        compile 'o.s.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    }

    jar {
        enabled = true
    }

    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

The project compiles now when building it with gradle.